# Какой вариант верный?

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно назвать спортсмена, занимающегося пауэрлифтингом? Встречала варианты: *пауэрлифтёр, пауэрлифтингёр, пауэрлифтингист*. Какой правильный?

Answer (score 3):

По результатам поиска в Google *пауэрлИфтер* - 279000 упоминаний, *пауэрлифтингист* - 1200, а *пауэрлифтингер* - 45. На мой взгляд, само слово *пауэрлифтинг* - слишком сложное для русского уха. Добавление суффикса -ист (пусть и русского) еще больше усложняет его. Продуктивная в английском словообразовательная модель с суффиксом -er подарила русскому языку много названий специальностей (типа менеджер, боксер, продюсер). В английском языке спортсмен, занимающийся  пауэрлифтингом, называется powerlifter. Почему бы не использовать это слово? Этот вариант более экономичный, чем два другие. В нем меньше суффиксов. Только не пауэрлифтЁр, а пауэрлИфтер (от *пауэрлИфтинг*).

Comment: Всё не так. Английский суффикс -er крайне редко появляется в случаях, когда слово заимствуется "по частям". Только целиком: голкипер есть, но нет "голкипа", кулер но без "кула" и т.д. Что же касается суффикса -ёр, то он скорее французский.    
Короче, если уж лифтингист не подходит, то придётся мириться с лифтёром.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - силовой троеборец или просто тяжелоатлет.
Ваши варианты словарями пока не фиксируются и, следовательно, все одинаково правильны и столько же неправильны. Я лично, если выбирать из трёх зол, склоняюсь к пауэрлифтингисту. Всё-таки русский суффикс (вернее - более обрусевший) тут достаточно продуктивен.

Comment: Спасибо всем!